# asp.net ajax client side freamwork failed to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Any one have an idea about this error?

> asp.net ajax client side framework failed to load

I am using Vb.net and I'm trying to use timer control.

Comment: I'm assuming its _client **side** framework_ ? Can you describe what control you are using, something from the ajax toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided:

Make sure you have the AJAX Extension:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=883

Get the latest toolkit if you're using it:
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Could be a little web config problem, see this:
http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/07/08/correcting-aspnet-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-error/

If you're using .NET 3.5 try installed .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: sorry this is error message 

asp.net ajax client -side framework faild to load

when i am Trying  to add timer control in ajax tool